# Apache: mod_rewrite & mod_substitute in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, proxy, reverse-proxy

The host which serves the client's web site only provides access to the .htaccess file.

I need a proxy which works fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^client.com$
RewriteRule ^special-dir(.*) https://partner.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Is it possible to integrate *mod_substitute* with this (only using the .htaccess)? I want to replace certain URLs in the partner's web site.

```
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute "s/badurl/goodurl/ni"
```

The combination of both doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, is the substitution module loaded at all into the http server? That is not exactly common...

Comment: Yes, mod_substitute is installed. I can use it to alter local outputs.

Comment: There is an interesting article about something similar: https://carstens.space/apache-mod-substitute-bei-einem-reverse-proxy/  It is in german language, but I assume google can help understanding the content. The main point seems to be to take care of the compression of the payload...

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the example of the article only works in an httpd.conf configuration, not in the .htaccess file. :/

Comment: Why that? Both the `SetOutputFilter` and the `Substitute` directive are explicitly documented as available in dynamic configuration files (".htaccess").

Comment: It both works separately in my .htaccess. The question is: How can you combine it?